# Centering advertising space on the website

Tags: html, css, centering

I use an ad network to sell advertising space on my website, but I can not in any way center this advertising space to be in the middle of the screen.

The problem seems to be in the CSS code that is related to the ad code that was assigned to me by this ad network.

In the picture below you can see that code, which I noticed a little, but I do not have that CSS style code anywhere in my files, I figured I just need to delete that part of the code where it says `display: block` and then everything will be fine, but I can't do that, because I do not have that code anywhere. The ad network provided that to me automatically when creating an advertising banner.

What can I do to get rid of that code and center the ad space?

[image]

```
<ins class="oneclerks gads_6287" data-revive-zoneid="2885" data-revive-id="5a92998f8535b04ba251e1de1a49283e" style="display: block; width: 728px; height: 90px; text-decoration: none;" data-revive-seq="0" id="revive-0-0" data-revive-loaded="1"><a href="https://swift.adclerks.com/www/delivery/ck.php?oaparams=2__bannerid=231__zoneid=2885__cb=5d071a349f__oadest=https%3A%2F%2Fadclerks.com" target="_blank"><img src="https://swift.adclerks.com/www/images/2cb696c2dd4a812c1c4e9f1d2fa32d7b.png" width="728" height="90" alt="" title="" border="0"></a><div id="beacon_5d071a349f" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; visibility: hidden;"><img src="https://swift.adclerks.com/www/delivery/lg.php?bannerid=231&amp;campaignid=99&amp;zoneid=2885&amp;loc=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.translatesubtitles.com%2F&amp;referer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&amp;cb=5d071a349f" width="0" height="0" alt="" style="width: 0px; height: 0px;"></div></ins>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `margin: 0 auto;` in you `ins` tag

```css
ins {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<ins class="oneclerks gads_6287" data-revive-zoneid="2885" data-revive-id="5a92998f8535b04ba251e1de1a49283e" style="display: block; width: 728px; height: 90px; text-decoration: none;" data-revive-seq="0" id="revive-0-0" data-revive-loaded="1"><a href="https://swift.adclerks.com/www/delivery/ck.php?oaparams=2__bannerid=231__zoneid=2885__cb=5d071a349f__oadest=https%3A%2F%2Fadclerks.com" target="_blank"><img src="https://swift.adclerks.com/www/images/2cb696c2dd4a812c1c4e9f1d2fa32d7b.png" width="728" height="90" alt="" title="" border="0"></a><div id="beacon_5d071a349f" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; visibility: hidden;"><img src="https://swift.adclerks.com/www/delivery/lg.php?bannerid=231&amp;campaignid=99&amp;zoneid=2885&amp;loc=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.translatesubtitles.com%2F&amp;referer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&amp;cb=5d071a349f" width="0" height="0" alt="" style="width: 0px; height: 0px;"></div></ins>
```